# Pandas 0.24 read_sql operational errors

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I just upgraded to Pandas 0.24.0 from 0.23.4 (Python 2.7.12), and many of my `pd.read_sql` queries are breaking. It looks like something related to MySQL, but it's strange that these errors only occur after updating my pandas version. Any ideas what's going on?

Here's my MySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE `xlations_topic_update_status` (
  `run_ts` datetime DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Here's my query:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
db_engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://<><>/product_analytics', echo=False)
pd.read_sql('select max(run_ts) from product_analytics.xlations_topic_update_status', con = db_engine).values[0][0]
```

And here's the error:

```
OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1059, "Identifier name 'select max(run_ts) from product_analytics.xlations_topic_update_status;' is too long") [SQL: 'DESCRIBE `select max(run_ts) from product_analytics.xlations_topic_update_status;`']
```

I've also gotten this for other more complex queries, but won't post them here.

Comment: Could it be that you are only using semicolon at the end of your read_sql string, where you shouldn't?

Comment: No, I tried removing the semicolon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) the first argument is either a string (a table name) or SQLAlchemy Selectable ([`select`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.select) or [`text`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text) object). In other words [`pd.read_sql()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) is delegating to [`pd.read_sql_table()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_table.html) and treating the entire query string as a table identifier.

Wrap your query string in a [`text()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text) construct first:

```
stmt = text('select max(run_ts) from product_analytics.xlations_topic_update_status')
pd.read_sql(stmt, con = db_engine).values[0][0]
```

This way [`pd.read_sql()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) will delegate to [`pd.read_sql_query()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html) instead. Another option is to call it directly.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `pd.read_sql_query(sql, con)`, instead of `pd.read_sql(...)`.

So:

```
pd.read_sql_query('select max(run_ts) from product_analytics.xlations_topic_update_status', con = db_engine).values[0][0]
```